# Diophantine Equations of the form $x^2 - n y^2 = 1$

Tags: diophantine-equations, python

I'm running into a problem with the execution of the [Chakravala method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakravala_method) of solving these equations. Running the algorithm through Python works up until $n=181$, at which point it executes all the way up until

$a=8524204405960630, b=633599123636484, k=-6$

I imagine after this point it runs into trouble due to $b$ being divisible by $6$. My question is, how can I avoid this? The resources I've seen don't explain what to do in that situation. Any and all assistance much appreciated.

Code snippet:

```
    for m in natural_number_generator(1):
    if (a + b * m) % abs(k) == 0:
        m_list.append(m)
        if m >= 2 * n:
            break
```

SOLVED:
Simple solution, my program was running off of Float variables and running into issues once it reached the value of $2^52$ (which breaks the float), and switching from / to // by the divisions (so that it's using integer variables), solved it entirely. Thank you very much to Sil :)

Comment: Your $(a,b,k)$ does not even solve the $a^2-181b^2=k$, so you have an error prior to that.

Comment: Very good point! Thank you for bringing it to my attention, that actually happens 3 steps prior in the algorithm. 

$a = 3784894978810275 b = 281329028190997 k = -4$
Between here and here it happens.

$a = 13676362270345184 b = 1016556001750318 k = 45 ,


a = 15333823118212874 b =1139754096335710 k = 26,


a = 8524204405960630 b = 633599123636484 k = -6$

Comment: Then I guess you can debug that, or if it is still a mathematical problem, consider including steps (in the main post) that got you from valid to invalid pair $a,b$.

Comment: Anyway If I'd have to wild guess, the last valid value of $a$ is dangerously close to $2^{52}$, which is the limit of integer values that double (floating point with double precision) can hold. So if you use floats (basically any division `/`  instead of `//`) in your program you could remove that and use integers instead, or rational numbers.

Comment: That's it! Thank you! The problem was that it was crossing over the $2^52$ boundary. To solve it in the program, all I did was replace a few / with //.

Comment: No problem, glad it works for you!